# Custom view not being added to FrameLayout for RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to inflate 2 custom drawings in each FrameLayout for a `CardView` inside a `RecyclerView` (`CustomDrawingA.java` and `CustomDrawingB.java`) respectively. How can I add these custom drawings from the Fragment itself rather than the `onBindViewHolder` method. I tried

> `setFrameLayoutA(android.widget.FrameLayout) in RecyclerViewListItem cannot be applied to (com.package.name.CustomDrawingA)`
>
> `setFrameLayoutB(android.widget.FrameLayout) in RecyclerViewListItem cannot be applied to (com.package.name.CustomDrawingB)`

**recyclerview_listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview_listitem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentPadding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardview_information_titlerow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_A"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_expandcollapsearrow"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_B"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout_A"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_B" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout_B"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout_A" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_C"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rectangle_grey"
            android:padding="5dp"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout_B" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_D"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout_B"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_C" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_E"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_D" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter class**

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mContext;

    RecyclerViewHeader header;
    List<RecyclerViewListItem> listItems;


    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, RecyclerViewHeader header, List<RecyclerViewListItem> listItems)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.header = header;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_headeritem, parent, false);
            return  new VHHeader(v);
        }
        else if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_listitem, parent, false);
            return new VHItem(v);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    private RecyclerViewListItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {       
        if (holder instanceof VHHeader)
        {
            VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader)holder;
            VHheader.txtTitle.setText(header.getHeading());
            VHheader.txtSubtitle.setText(header.getSubheading());
        }
        else if (holder instanceof VHItem)
        {
            RecyclerViewListItem currentItem = getItem(position-1);
            VHItem VHitem = (VHItem)holder;

            VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.setText(R.string.fa_icon_chevron_up);
            VHitem.txtExpandCollapseArrow.setTypeface(iconFont);

            VHitem.txtA.setText(currentItem.getName());
            VHitem.txtB.setText(currentItem.getDescription());
            VHitem.txtC.setText(currentItem.getNewstatus());
            VHitem.txtD.setText(currentItem.getGlutenstatus());
            VHitem.txtE.setText(currentItem.getSuitability());
        
            VHitem.flA.addView(new CustomDrawingA(mContext));
            VHitem.flB.addView(new CustomDrawingB(mContext));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position)
    {
        return position == 0;
    }

    //increasing getItemcount to 1. This will be the row of header.
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size()+1;
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtTitle, txtSubtitle;
        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_header__heading);
            this.txtSubtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_header__subheading);
        }
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtExpandCollapseArrow, txtA, txtB, txtC, txtD, txtE;
        FrameLayout flA, flB;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.txtExpandCollapseArrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_expandcollapsearrow);

            this.txtA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_A);
            this.txtB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_B);
            this.txtC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_C);
            this.txtD = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_D);
            this.txtE = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_E);

            this.flA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.framelayout_A);
            this.flB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.framelayout_B);

            /** WORKING CODE BUT NEED AN 'itemA.[XYZ]' VERSION OF THIS TO SET IN FRAGMENT (start) */
            if(position == 1){
                VHitem.flA.addView(new CustomDrawingA(mContext));
                VHitem.flB.addView(new CustomDrawingB(mContext));
            }else if(position == 2){    
                VHitem.flA.addView(new CustomDrawingC(mContext));
                VHitem.flB.addView(new CustomDrawingD(mContext));
            }else if(position == 3){    
                VHitem.flA.addView(new CustomDrawingE(mContext));
                VHitem.flB.addView(new CustomDrawingF(mContext));
            }
            /** WORKING CODE BUT NEED AN 'itemA.[XYZ]' VERSION OF THIS TO SET IN FRAGMENT (end) */

        }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewListItem class**

```
public class RecyclerViewListItem {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private FrameLayout frameLayoutA;
    private FrameLayout frameLayoutB;
    private String newstatus;
    private String glutenstatus;
    private String suitability;

    public RecyclerViewListItem(){}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public FrameLayout getFrameLayoutA() {
        return frameLayoutA;
    }

    public void setFrameLayoutA(FrameLayout frameLayoutA) {
        this.frameLayoutA = frameLayoutA;
    }

    public FrameLayout getFrameLayoutB() {
        return frameLayoutB;
    }

    public void setFrameLayoutB(FrameLayout frameLayoutB) {
        this.frameLayoutB = frameLayoutB;
    }

    public String getNewstatus() {
        return newstatus;
    }

    public void setNewstatus(String newstatus) {
        this.newstatus = newstatus;
    }

    public String getGlutenstatus() {
        return glutenstatus;
    }

    public void setGlutenstatus(String glutenstatus) {
        this.glutenstatus = glutenstatus;
    }

    public String getSuitability() {
        return suitability;
    }

    public void setSuitability(String suitability) {
        this.suitability = suitability;
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private FrameLayout frameLayoutA;
    private FrameLayout frameLayoutB;

    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), getHeader(), getListItems());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    public RecyclerViewHeader getHeader()
    {
        RecyclerViewHeader header = new RecyclerViewHeader();
        header.setHeading("Desserts");
        header.setSubheading("All made fresh daily");
        return header;
    }

    public List<RecyclerViewListItem> getListItems()
    {
        List<RecyclerViewListItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

            RecyclerViewListItem itemA = new RecyclerViewListItem();
            itemA.setName("Crème Brûlée");
            itemA.setDescription("Caramalised vanilla crème with an almond tuile");

            itemA.setFrameLayoutA(new CustomDrawingA(getContext()));
            itemA.setFrameLayoutB(new CustomDrawingB(getContext()));
            itemA.setNewstatus(" New ");
            itemA.setGlutenstatus("Gluten free");
            itemA.setSuitability("Suitable for vegetarians" + "\n" + "Suitable for coeliacs" + "\n" + "Halal friendly" + "\n" + "Kosher friendly");
            listItems.add(itemA);

            RecyclerViewListItem itemB = new RecyclerViewListItem();
            itemB.setName("Bûche de Noël");
            itemB.setNewstatus(" New ");
            itemB.setGlutenstatus("Gluten free");
            itemB.setSuitability("Suitable for vegetarians" + "\n" + "Suitable for coeliacs");
            listItems.add(itemB);

            RecyclerViewListItem itemC = new RecyclerViewListItem();
            itemC.setName("Croquembouche");
            itemC.setNewstatus(" New ");
            itemC.setGlutenstatus("Gluten free");
            itemC.setSuitability("Suitable for vegetarians" + "\n" + "Suitable for coeliacs");
            listItems.add(itemC);
}
```

**Current result**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewHolder is accessible only through Adapter. You cannot add the views directly from the activity. It's no way possible

Comment: I am not using an activity. I am using a fragment.

Comment: Even fragment, you can't add it directly